# How do I use user-created R functions inside F#?

Tags: r, f#

I have my own R function that I would like to use in F#. How do I do this?

```ml
open RProvider
open RDotNet

let f1 = R.eval(R.parse(text="function(x) x + 1")).AsFunction()

// I expect the following line to give me 5 but it doesn't work
f1([|4|])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call the function, you have to pass the value to R using the type provider. Then, call the function with the passed in data on the R side, and finally bring the result back into F#:

```
let res = R.sapply(R.c(4),f1).AsInteger().[0]
```

This producess the following output

> val f1 : Function
>
> val res : int = 5

You can find more information on http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/passing-data.html

In particular, the statistics walk-through shows an extended example of the passing back and forth technique, including with data.frames: http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/Statistics-QuickStart.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I saw that example, but that explicitly passes the data from F# to R, computes in R, and then brings back into F#. It is much more "automatic" with the built-in R functions, like R.sum([|4;3|]) in this question here. Can I do this with my own functions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122687/how-to-write-a-sum-function-in-f-using-rprovider/19122968#19122968

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it, However I'm still learning R provider too

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Jaskula answered, the proper technique is to pass to R and evaluate on that side.

Here is another example that doesn't rely on assignment of the function to an F# variable:

Another example:

```
R.assign("y",[|1;2;3|])
let z = R.eval(R.parse(text="
    f2 <- function(x) x + 2
    f2(y)")).AsInteger() |> Seq.toArray
```

> val z : int [] = [|3; 4; 5|]